# Change ListView divider from ArrayAdapter class?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a class (foo) extending ListActivity which instantiates a class (fooAdap) extending ArrayAdapter. In fooAdap, there is the getview() method where I populate my ListView.

From the foo class, I can call getListView().setDividerHeight(0) and make the divider disappear. Is there a way to access that method from getView() in fooAdap?

foo.java

```
public class foo extends ListActivity
{
   ...
   protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
      ...
      ListView lv = getListView ();
      lv.setDividerHeight (0);
      fooAdap foo = new fooAdap (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, mRowData);
      ...
   }
```

fooAdap.java

```
public class fooAdap extends ArrayAdapter
{
   ...

   public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
      ...

      switch (position)
      {
         case 1: // show divider for these rows in listview
         case 2:
         break;

         case 3: // hide divider for this row in listview
         break;
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: does my answer helps you if not thn please let me know i will sought this out for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making my own divider and setting the ListView dividerHeight() to 0 in the XML layout.

I have a separate layout for the ListView rows and added another LinearLayout and TextView there. I then copied the file divider_horizontal_dark.9.png from the android sdk directory into my res/ directory and set the background of the new TextView to it as well as setting MaxHeight to 1dp for the textview.

Now I can just toggle the LinearLayout to View.VISIBLE or View.GONE within getView() method.  Long way around, but seems to get me what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You to have pass currentActivity Object to fooAdap and there it can be done easily.

OR you can pass that Activity object through fooAdap Constructor.

```
 Activity currentActivity=foo.this;

     fooAdap foo = new fooAdap (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, mRowData);
    foo.currentActivity=currentActivity;


    public class fooAdap extends ArrayAdapter
    {
    Activity currentActivity;

    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
       {
          ...

          switch (position)
          {
             case 1: // show divider for these rows in listview

             case 2:
             break;

             case 3: // hide divider for this row in listview
              this.currentActivity.getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
             break;
          }
          ...
       }


    }
```

This will surely help you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This does allow me to access getListView() but causes it to draw oddly when scrolling. Still experimenting.